# How to sqlite query fire on latitude and longitude between 100 meter distance from my current GPS location in Android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, google-maps

I have sqlite database on static data put in my assets folder from Android project.

I will write query and fetch data from sqlite database and insert addMarker on google map on lat & long between 100 meter distance from gps location lat & long got but not correct record getting query.

This is query I would write on database

```
SELECT * FROM tblLatLong WHERE (latitude='33.247006' and longitude='-86.576707') < 100;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll get location from your `SQLite` then find a distance between Two points(SQLite Point and your Current Location Point) using

> distanceBetween(double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double
>   endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)

### Get Distance:

```
float[] results = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(SQLitePosition.latitude, SQLitePosition.longitude,
            CurrentPosition.latitude, CurrentPosition.longitude, results);
```

or another method

> distanceTo(Location dest)

and check that distance is `< 100` then only add that Point into your `Google Map` as a Marker.

Comment: Thanks for reply but can you please explain in detail about SQLitePosition.latitude, SQLitePosition.longitude this lat & long when to find out ??????????

Comment: @najibputhawala SQLite Position it means the point that you fetch from your DB..

Comment: Can you write again sql query which i need to it ?

Comment: @najibputhawala Do you get my Point?? There is no SQL Query for that....You'll check this distance manually..

Comment: Yes i got your point and its on location based got the distance but  i need to distance on sqlite db from table throw fetch record. so give me your suggestion.

Comment: @najibputhawala No budy that's not possible.... sorry!!!